# subdomains configuration overwritten by default configuration

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I am trying to configure some subdomains in apache2 (no master domain defined) and, after I write the config file for a certain domain, enable it and then try to load it, it shows me the content set by the default config file (I restarted apache). Here is a virtual host for a subdomain:

```
#nameVirtualHost * virtualHost *
<VirtualHost subdomain.domain.com>
ServerAdmin email@email.com
ServerName subdomain.domain.com
ServerAlias subdomain.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/clients/subdomain
        <Directory /var/www/clients/subdomain>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_subdomain.com.log

        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_subdomain.com.log combined
        ServerSignature Off
UseCanonicalName off
</VirtualHost>
```

In the default config file, the path is '/var/www'.

I know that this must be supereasy, but can't catch on. Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use, assuming you want standard HTTP on port 80 :

```
nameVirtualHost *:80
```

and then in any VirtualHost parts :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain.domain.com
...
</VirtualHost>
```

see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html